# RStudio, Prospect package errors in matplot Binning function

Tags: r

I want to noise removal from spectroscopy signal data. I have using the "Prospect" package with RStudio.

I'm beginner in R. I don't understand the next error (see point 4)

My Script is:

```
wav= read.table(file= "LS2017_ suel_SWIR-formJul.csv", header=T, sep=";", dec=",") 

wav <- as.matrix(wav[  , 2:ncol(wav)]) 
str(wav)

clrs <- sample (colors(), 1) 

clrs[c(1)] <- "black"


ejex <-1950 : 2400


matplot(ejex, type="l",xaxt= "n",xlim=c(1950 ,2400), ylim=c(0,1),xlab="longitud de onda (nm)",ylab="Reflectancia")
matlines(ejex,t(wav ), col= clrs,lty=1) 

axis(side= 1, at= seq(0, 2400,50), las= 2)
par(usr=c(0.0, 1.0, 0, 2400),xaxp=c(0,2400,50))


ejex <-1950 : 2400

X <- movav(wav, w = 11) 


clrs <- sample (colors(), 1) 

clrs[c(1)] <- "red2"

plot(as.numeric(colnames(wav)), wav[1 , ], type = "l", xlab = "Wavelength",
     ylab = "Reflectance")

lines(as.numeric(colnames(X)), X[ , ], col = clrs)


 plot(as.numeric(colnames(wav)), wav[1 , ], type = "l", xlab = "Wavelength",
      ylab = "Reflectance")
```

> Error in plot.window(...) : se necesitan valores finitos de 'xlim'
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In plot(as.numeric(colnames(wav)), wav[1, ], type = "l", xlab = "Wavelength",  :
>     NAs introduced by coercion
>   2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
>
> lines(as.numeric(colnames(X)), X[ , ], col = clrs)
>   Warning message:
>   In lines(as.numeric(colnames(X)), X[, ], col = clrs) :
>     NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Why do you want to make `colnames` numeric?

Comment: because is a date frame